# Forward value from signals within a QStateMachine

Tags: qt

I am currently having trouble with a QStateMachine in QT. Basically I want to use it to control the flow between my screens, e.g. to switch from a master page to a detail page.

What I basically have is this:

```
// Overview
QState* overviewState = new QState();
overviewState->assignProperty(ui->stackedWidget, "currentIndex", 0);
stateMachine->addState(overviewState);

// Editor
QState* editorState = new QState();
editorState ->assignProperty(ui->stackedWidget, "currentIndex", 1);
stateMachine->addState(editorState);

// Overview -> Editor
overviewState->addTransition(overview, SIGNAL(onEditor()), editorState);
```

So far this is working as expected. The overview emits `onEditor` and the editor is shown. However, now I want to forward a value from the signal. The editor can be called with a selected value (meaning the user wants to edit an entry) or without a value (meaning the user starts with an empty editor). The overview would then have two signals: `onEditor` and `onEditor(long)`. The editor would have two slots: `performInitialize` and `performInitialize(long)`.

```
connect(editorState, SIGNAL(entered()), editor, SLOT(performInitialize()));
```

This is the point where I am stuck. (How) can I forward the signal from `onEditor(long)` to `performInitialize(long)`? The signal from the `QState` surely has no knowledge of this additional parameter. How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the initialization into setup and performance stages:

```
void Editor::performInitialize(long val); // current implementation - keep it

void Editor::setupInitialize(long val);
  m_initVal = val;
}

void Editor::performInitialize() {
  performInitialize(m_initVal);
}

connect(overview, SIGNAL(onEditor(long)), editor, SLOT(setupInitialize(long)));
overviewState->addTransition(overview, SIGNAL(onEditor(long)), editorState);
```

`addTransition` sets up an internal connection to the signal. Qt guarantees that slots are executed in the order of connection. Thus the state transition is guaranteed never to precede `setupInitialize` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks like a clean solution that should definitely work.